# update query is not working in sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Have a Database with various table. I need to update a String value in table1.

I have a string in activity1.And passed the String value to DBhelper from Activity1.Like this.

```
private void goTokey() {

        check="premium";
        dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);
        dbHelper.sample(check);
}
```

I got a value in DBHelper and I need to update that value in database in table1.

```
DBHelper.class

public  void sample( String prms) {
        Log.d("DBHELPER SUCCESS", prms);

        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
            db1.execSQL("update table1 SET status = '"+prms+"' WHERE id = 1 ");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("GET SAMPLE VALUE"+e);
        }
    }
```

For reference of DBHelper.class [view here](http://pastebin.com/fLLwQmsY)

What's wrong with my syntax?

I got exception like this from some where..

```
02-28 12:09:45.604: I/System.out(4975): GET SAMPLE VALUEandroid.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table report already exists (code 1): , while compiling: create table report(level TEXT, topic TEXT,  start TEXT, end TEXT, date TEXT)
```

How to achieve this to update the value into database?

Comment: post your dbhelper class code here...have you created constructor in dbhelper class

Comment: Yes I have check it here http://pastebin.com/fLLwQmsY @Vamshi

Comment: too much code in dbhelper, separate other code from that class only add db related code in that class...i feel somewhere you are calling database creation and table creation code every time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from this

```
public  void sample( String prms) {
        Log.d("DBHELPER SUCCESS", prms);

        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
            db1.execSQL("update table1 SET status = '"+prms+"' WHERE id = 1 ");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("GET SAMPLE VALUE"+e);
        }
    }
```

to this

```
public  void sample( String prms) {
        Log.d("DBHELPER SUCCESS", prms);
        try
        {
         ContentValues content =new ContentValues();
            content.put(STATUS, prms);
            long l= myDataBase.update(APP_TABLE, content,null, null);
            System.out.print("HELLO NEW INSER CODE----"+l);
        } catch(Exception e){
            //System.out.println("NO UPDATE IN APPSTATUS");
        }
    }
```